# I/O Error when attempting to install the latest Ubuntu? How can I fix this?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive, hardware

Well the latest Ubuntu has shipped and though I would love to use it on my new used Thinkpad for programming, when ever I install it I get an Error saying something to the effect: "I/O Error... Faulty Disk/CD... or faulty HDD, etc."

I see this is fairly common on the new Ubuntu installation medias and I do not know how to address this. I can provide further information but I am starting to loose hope. I have only 1 USB-HDD-stick of 128 GB and the installer made sure to wipe my HDD before alerting me of the error (which is really stupid because it is alerting you of an error that is irrecoverable LEGIT RIGHT after whipping your HDD).

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install smartmontools 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  gsmartcontrol smart-notifier mailx | mailutils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  smartmontools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 525 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,087 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 smartmontools amd64 7.1-1build1 [525 kB]
Fetched 525 kB in 1s (529 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package smartmontools.
(Reading database ... 187343 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../smartmontools_7.1-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking smartmontools (7.1-1build1) ...
Setting up smartmontools (7.1-1build1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/smartd.service → /lib/systemd/system/smartmontools.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/smartmontools.service → /lib/systemd/system/smartmontools.service.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3) ...
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda 
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Hitachi/HGST Travelstar Z7K500
Device Model:     HGST HTS725050A7E630
Serial Number:    TF655AWH07WHKL
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 77ec395d6
Firmware Version: GH2ZB550
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Jul  9 19:10:45 2020 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda 
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Enabled.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -c /dev/sda 
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   45) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  88) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda 
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 2 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Thu Jul  9 19:14:40 2020 UTC
Use smartctl -X to abort test.
```

Soo... The short test yield.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda 
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15274         -
# 2  Vendor (0x50)       Completed without error       00%      9005         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9005         -
```

-------NEWS FLASH-----UPON INSTALLATION THIS IS THE OUTPUT/INFO

> WARNING: This will destroy all data on any partitions you have removed
> as well as on the partitions that are going to be formatted.
>
> The partition tables of the following devices are changed:  SCSI1
> (0,0,0) (sda)
>
> The following partitions are going to be formatted:  partition #1 of
> SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as   partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4
>
> The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:
> [Error no. 5] Input/output error
>
> This is soften due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard
> disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower
> speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often
> available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk
> is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler
> environment.
>
> Installer Crashed: We're sorry; the installer crashed. After you close
> this window, we'll allow you to file a bug report using the integrated
> bug reporting tool. This will gather information about your system and
> your installation process. The details will be sent to our bug tracker
> and a developer will attend to the problem as soon as possible.
>
> This problem was already reported in the bug report displayed in the
> web browser. PLEASE check if you can add any further information that
> might be helpful; for the developers.
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1874662

Comment: It's not common at all...and you seem to be describing a hardware fault, not an Ubuntu issue. Look up how to run a SMART test on your HDD to verify that it's dying (or dead). Ubuntu is not designed to run on faulty hardware.

Comment: user535733 is right. But what media is causing the I/O error? Is it the drive you want to install Ubuntu on or is it the drive you use as installation media? I ask this because recently I reinstalled Ubuntu myself and got the same message. It happened after the installation media check that Ubuntu always tries to do. I tried again and cancelled the installation media check and everything went fine so I'm not sure that it really isn't an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Yes, this is a fairly new test and I preformed the short SMART test and I posted the results. Do you think it is an Ubuntu problem? I think it's an Ubuntu problem, also saying "An Ubuntu" is so weird.

Comment: So yea, wtf Ubuntu?!?

Answer (score 0):

When you see this error next time unplug USB and plug it into another USB port. The setup will continue from where it was stopped.